# How to wrap an element with html using jQuery

Tags: jquery

This is my HTML code:

```
<div class="content">
<h2>title</h2>
</div>
```

Is there any way to use jQuery to add links for h2 tags like:

```
<div class="content">
<a href="my-link"><h2>title</h2></a>
</div>
```

Comment: you can use `appendChild` in [javescript](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp) or `apend()` in [jquey](https://api.jquery.com/append/) to do it. And the `<a>` tag can be included inside `<h2>` and work the same.

Comment: Please show me how to make my example above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the jQuery `.wrap()` function described here
https://api.jquery.com/wrap/

In your case it would be:

```
$("h2").wrap('<a href="https://www.google.com/"></a>');
```